# Completely Cython-ize application

Tags: python, cython

Is it possible to use Cython to completely compile/link a Python 3 application to an executable format (assuming all used modules are cythonizable, of course).

I'm working under Linux and I would like to get an ELF binary with as little dependencies as possible.

Comment: I'm waiting and watching to see what comes of this question.  In the meantime, docker seems like a valid solution that works across platforms better than ELFs, works generic to the language, and can include additional components such as filesystem components (some pyhton modules need them) or additional components easily, while also obviating the need for your executable bundle.

Comment: @DanFarrell: Docker is not a viable option, for me, as I'm targeting embedded systems. While none is taking the bait here, I'm exploring the [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html) alternative.

Comment: I hope you can share your experiences here.  it's an interesting problem and I'm curious how it works out for you.  This is one of the things I love about Go - really easy to build and distribute binaries.  but I'm sure you want to stay in  the python world.  Best of luck, let us know what you find.

Comment: @DanFarrell: I am working to integrate Nuitka into Buildroot. It seems to do what needed, but cross-compilation is not straightforward (to be polite). If I manage to have it working I'll detail things here.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the answer is no. The C code generated by Cython from even the simplest of Python programs will contain a lot of CPython API calls. Thus, any program generated via Cython will have CPython as a dependency.

In the past I have successfully created standalone Python 3 binaries using [cx_Freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io), though on Windows. The linked page claims that it "should work on any platform that Python itself works on". If you also need the added performance benefits of Cython, the two can be mixed freely.